# Using the ATL OLE DB Provider template

Tags: c++, oledb, atl, provider

I am experimenting with trying to write an OLEDB provider.  I have started with the ATL OLE DB provider wizard.  After fixing an apparent issue with the COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY2 macro I managed to get the default code to compile, but so far I'm not having much success using it.

For example, I have tried using VB.NET to connect to it as such:

```
Dim testConn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=TestProvider.Provider.1")
testConn.Open()
Dim strTest As String = "C:\*.*"

Dim testCmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strTest, testConn)

Dim testRd As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
testRd = testCmd.ExecuteReader()
```

The last line produces an `InvalidOperationException` with additional information: `OleDbDataAdapter internal error: invalid row set accessor: Ordinal=1 Status=BADBINDINFO`.

Trying to use ADO from VBA in Access lets me correctly pull the field names, but when I try to get any actual values I get a rather generic "multi-step OLE DB operation produced errors" message.

I have tried reading up on binding and accessors, but there doesn't seem to be anything relevant to change in the template code.  Is there something else I might be doing wrong?  I have tried creating a new column map and replacing all of the FindFirstFile code with different fields with hardcoded values, but am still getting the same errors.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 RC, but I don't think it's an IDE-related issue.

Comment: On C++/ATL side you need to trace extended information about the error using `AtlTraceErrorRecords` function. This normally provides more informative messages and expands "multi-step operation errors". The error detail is already lost on VB.NET side code.

Comment: Thank you, but AtlTraceErrorRecords does not seem to be helping much.  The output that I am getting is

`atlTraceDBClient - Binding entry 0 failed. Status: 3`
`atlTraceDBClient - Binding entry 1 failed. Status: 3`
`atlTraceDBClient - OLE DB Error Record dump for hr = 0x80040e21`
`atlTraceDBClient - No OLE DB Error Information found: hr = 0x80004005`

Comment: You need to step code through to find out what exactly is generating this binding failure. It can be connection string, or something else. This is pure guessing since it is not so obvious in first place, an you don't post any code for C++ side.

Comment: take a look at the two answers for [how to update row data fetched using ATL OLE database in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306475/how-to-update-row-data-fetched-using-atl-ole-database-in-c-from-simple-sql-ser) which contains a suggestion from @RomanR. as well as what I finally figured out for my question.  It may help.

Comment: By the way, why is the code sample in VB but the tag is C++?